# Is it possible to avoid thread.sleep() with Google Cloud Messaging?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

The link https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html provided by Google explains how to implement Google Cloud Messaging in a Android app.

In particular, in the service which handles the reception of messages, within the `onHandleIntent`method, the tutorial uses this code:

```
else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            // This loop represents the service doing some work.
            for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                        + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            // Post notification of received message.
            sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
            Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
        }
```

This forces the app to wait for 25 seconds before posting the notification.
Why does the tutorial uses that? Is it really necessary?

Comment: Did you read the comment at the top of the loop?

Comment: Of course... Did you read my question? Because this comment doesn't answer it.

Comment: It's there to "represent(s) the service doing some work". The work is not what the tutorial is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's there because of the reason stated in the comment right above it!

`This loop represents the service doing some work.`

It's example code, simulating some real work being done in that section.

Comment: I did read the comment, it's a shame I have to mention it... I just don't understand if this is supposed to be replaced by my own code or if it is necessary for Cloud Messaging to work.